# write-excel-file with schema using a buffer

Tags: node.js, excel, typescript, nestjs

I'm writing a nestjs controller endpoint that sends a response. I understand that the response needs to be a buffer.
I want to use the [***write-excel-file***](https://www.npmjs.com/package/write-excel-file) library using a schema, as explained in the documentation. Is it possible to do so if I want a *buffer*?

I tried calling the `writeXlsxFile` function using both *schema* and *buffer* flag, but it isn't letting me..

```
await writeXlsxFile(data, {schema: mySchema, buffer: true, ... })
```

Error:

```
Buffer does not exist in type WithSchemaOptions<Data>
```